# How do I limit the find and replace procedure to execute only on certain pages?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using Microsoft Visual Basic on Word. I want to limit the find and replace function to operate only on certain pages of the document. How do I do it?

As of now, it will execute it the whole document which is not preferred.

```
Sub X_entity()
'
' Replaces lower and greater than symbols to html entity
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ">"
        .Replacement.Text = "&gt;"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "<"
        .Replacement.Text = "&lt;"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Comment: A quick fix would be to replace `.Wrap = wdFindContinue` with `.Wrap = wdFindStop`. This will ensure that `Find` only operates on the selected area. You can further improve this by using the [`Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range) object instead of `Selection`. Your code will need to define the [start and end positions of the range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.setrange) that you want `Find` to operate on. You can find more help [here](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/SelectCurPage.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Selection (which is poor practice anyway), you should point to the range of each page in turn, using Find/Replace on the designated range only. For example:

```
Sub ProcessPages()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, ArrPgs()
' Define the pages to process
ArrPgs = Array("7", "4", "3", "2")
For i = 0 To UBound(ArrPgs)
  ' Process the defined pages
  With ActiveDocument.Range.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=ArrPgs(i)).GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page").Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Text = ">"
    .Replacement.Text = "&gt;"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "<"
    .Replacement.Text = "&lt;"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

With the above code, the pages are processed in reverse order in case the Find/Replace messes with the pagination.